# MVC 3 RenderSection Issues with Jquery Mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

Please somebody put me out of my misery, I am attempting to simply render a section in my header with the following code in my layout.cshtml

```
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script src="@ResourceHelper.Site.MobileScriptUrl("jquery-1.5.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@ResourceHelper.Site.MobileCSSUrl("jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@ResourceHelper.Site.MobileScriptUrl("jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@ResourceHelper.Site.MobileCSSUrl("default.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- render page specific header content -->
@if (IsSectionDefined("HeaderContent"))
{
    @RenderSection("HeaderContent")
}
</head>
```

In my content page I have a simple :

```
@model DRTPortal.Models.VehicleModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Real Time Vehicle Location";
Layout = "~/Areas/Mobile/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section HeaderContent { code here }
```

If I view source then there is no header content rendered, but if i remove the jquery mobile 1.0a4.1.min javascript reference then the header code is rendered.

has anybody come across this before?

cheers,

Paul.

Comment: just to add that i cannot get any @Rendersection to work while the jquery mobile script is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was to remove the @section HeaderContent and just plainly insert the javascript block in the content within the html tags.

I know the scripts should be in the header, what are the issues i could face by doing this?

Paul.